# Commands to monitor performance counters of a unix machine

Tags: java, linux, unix, performancecounter

I am developing a tool where I need to get the performance counters like( processor speed, cpu usage, memory ) and display them graphically.

to monitor a windows system I have used commonds like

`command="typeperf "+hostname+" \"\\processor(_total)\\% processor time\" -si 00:00:05";` for cpu usage

`command="typeperf "+hostname+" \"\\memory\\Available Bytes\" -si 00:00:05";` for free memory

`command="typeperf "+hostname+" \"\\paging file(_Total)\\% Usage\" -si 00:00:05";` for page file usage

and then I have used

`p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));`

to get the counters and next I send these values  to a graph...

If I want to  monitor these counters for a unix/linux machine how to do it? what is the procedure..

please inform me how to read these counters and what are the respective commands and how to execute them.

Thank you all

Comment: Google would help you much more at this stage than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3580294: I couldn't get the exact answer man thats why I asked

Comment: You'll probably want to be far more specific than "how to read these counters and what are the respective commands and how to execute them." Google will definitely tell you the answers to the first two parts, and the last one *should* be similar to the way you did things on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few commnds which you can use.

**free** (Will give you memory usage and Swap usage)

**top** (Will give you CPU Utilization along with memory utilization, This command itself can serve your requirement.)

You will need to use awk/sed to capture the specific values and feed it to user program.

Comment: yup, we just need an additional installation for that.If I am not wrong "free" and "top" would be available on all *nix